# Use findstr to replace null values with empty strings from sqlcmd command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cmd, sqlcmd

I have an sqlcmd command which generates a csv file from a view. Is it possible to replace the NULL values to empty string using the findstr command?

Here is what I tried.

```
sqlcmd -S . -d SAMPLEDB -U sa -P pass -s"|" -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF select * from view_Table" > Sample.csv -h -1 | findstr /v /c:"NULL"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily build the `extraction SQL` for each view using the system management views. This simple query:

```
SELECT v.[name]
      ,c.[name]
      ,c.[column_id]
      ,c.[is_nullable]
FROM sys.views V
INNER JOIN sys.columns C
    ON V.[object_id] = C.[object_id];
```

will return everything we need to perform the task:

- the view name
- the column name
- the column order
- if the column is nullable

So, we need only to build the extraction SQL statements:

```
SELECT v.[name]
      ,'SELECT ' + DS.[definition] + ' FROM ' + v.[name]
FROM sys.views V
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + CASE WHEN c.[is_nullable] = 1 THEN 'ISNULL(' + c.[name] + ','''')' ELSE c.[name] END
            FROM sys.columns C
            WHERE V.[object_id] = C.[object_id]
            ORDER BY c.[column_id]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    )
) DS ([definition]);
```

Depending on your SQL version you can reduce the code above - for example using [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Also, you can add `WHERE` clause to filter the query for specific views.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sql in the command string to select fields individually and do an ISNULL on them

```
select * from view_Table
```

To

```
select  ISNULL([FIELD_1],''''),ISNULL([FIELD_2],'''') from view_Table
```

in you calling string

use the following code to build it and check to see the final statement runs

```
DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Temp = 'SELECT  ISNULL([FIELD_1],''''),ISNULL([FIELD_2],'''') FROM view_Table'
SELECT @Temp
```